why finalization of chain stops after adding more than 1 validator on single node?
i have my substrate blockchain running with 3 validator setup .when i add more than 1 validator on single node and i.e sometimes even 3 or 4 the finalization of my chain stops .
what is the reason behind it , is it also happen on polkadot mainnet or testnet , if no  how they have stopped someone from adding more than one validator on single node
